# Shadow map in Babylon JS

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

Im somewhat new to Babylon JS but I created a scene and filled it with some cubes, added a light and a shadow map using:

```
new BABYLON.ShadowGenerator(4096, light);
```

Im getting really aliased shadow edges. I would like to know how I can get the aliasing to be smaller without bumping up the shadow map size.

[image]

Its already at 4096 which is already fairly large. Am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that how spread out shadow casting objects are makes a difference in the shadow quality. For example, go here and change the "distance_range" var to 10:

https://playground.babylonjs.com/#ZSB485#3

I ended up just using `shadowGenerator.useBlurExponentialShadowMap = true` and that seemed to be good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

you can try using one of the soft shadows flag, while reducing the shadow map size, because as you say - 4096 is way too large.

You can read more about it [here](https://doc.babylonjs.com/babylon101/shadows#soft-shadows), and try the following

```
shadowGenerator.useExponentialShadowMap = true;
// or!
shadowGenerator.usePoissonSampling = true;
```